# How to use ASP.net login source code on cluster servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I use asp.net with c# for my simple web form and use following source code for login page

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conn1);
if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    conn.Open();
}
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [LG_INFO] where USER_NAME='" + txtUserName.Text + "' AND  PASSWD=HASHBYTES('SHA2_512','" + txtPasswd.Text + "');", conn);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.HasRows == true)
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        Session["username"] = dr.GetValue(2).ToString();
        Session["memID"] = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
        Session["memFULLNAME"] = dr.GetValue(7).ToString();
        Session["fname"] = dr.GetValue(8).ToString();                  
        cusfname = dr.GetValue(8).ToString();

        if (ViewState["Cusstatus"].ToString() == "1")
        {
            Response.Redirect("MainPage.aspx");
            
        }
```

This code is working on my UAT environment. But when I upload to hosting servers(cluster servers) this login process is not working and didn't redirect to main page . hosting provider suggest

> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=314055

for more information. I doesn't have any idea for how to change above mentioned code for using MAC validation. Please give some help for rectify this issue.

Comment: Look up 'sql injection attack'.   Your code is a classic attack vector.  You should NEVER create SQL statements by concatenating user input.

Comment: I would start by using SQL Server Management Studio to connect to database for same machine.  The error messages are much better in SSMS than c# to help isolate issues.  You can also look at logs files in SSMS to get complete error messages.  I just spent a few weeks getting a database setup for all Domain Users to connect to database.  Had lots of issues.  Without viewing log files I kept on getting same error in c#, but actually was fixing issues and only the log file told me when I was fixed one issue and then got next issue.